# When to enforce atomicity or volatile access to fields in the UI thread?

Tags: java, android, concurrency

To better understand concurrency (as a newbie), I need to know how exactly memory in the main (UI) thread is shared with worker threads.

For example, with AsyncTask I have never needed to use keywords like synchronized or volatile, or assign fields in the main thread as atomic using AtomicReferences. *From what I've read*, this is because AsyncTask was designed to use the main thread's background thread pool, and because of its location it has shared access to these variables (such as calling publishProgress() to update a progress bar's percentage).

But when I use a standard Thread instance, and from inside that instance I assign a new value to a variable in the main thread... if I read that value from the main thread it is not updated. So does Android only enforce atomicity for special cases like AsyncTask?

For instance:

```
private class ExportAllTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();

            write_complete = false;//this update is visible in the main thread
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids)
    {
        //do stuff
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        write_complete = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled()
    {
        super.onCancelled();

        write_complete = true;
    }
}
```

Allows a callback from a subscriber in the main thread to respond according to the state of write_complete at any point in the AsyncTask's lifecycle.

But if I used a basic Thread (just wrote this for example purposes):

```
private void simple_export()
{
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            write_complete = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < some_int; i++)
            {
                //do stuff
            }

            write_complete = true;
        }
    }.run();
}
```

write_complete's "publication" is invisible to accessors within the main thread. Now, I could run this thread on the UI. *But for asynchronous purposes* at certain points I also want the Thread to sleep, or wait for a CountdownLatch to release because of updates occurring in the UI. Now, if I run this "on" the UI thread, sleeping will hang the entire activity. Which I don't want.

So really, I want to know the answer to the question in the title, specific to Android:

When should one enforce atomicity (or volatile access) to fields in the UI thread for shared access to worker threads? Disclaimer: without using a handler (which is a solution, but unnecessary for essentially 1 task).

--

**Update**: I learned a little about how the concurrency package works in Android. I have a WRAPPER Boolean variable and an object variable defined in the Activity scope. The synchronize block was useful for WRITING to objects accessed by multiple worker threads. For instance, an AsyncTask and a Thread accessing the Boolean required the Boolean to be synchronized within the Thread because it updated the value. The AsyncTask also updated the value in onPreExecute but did not require locking because it instantiates the Thread instance (and has the background thread pool signature). The object (defined type) needed to have the volatile keyword but could not be synchronized (unsure why).

Edit: Corrected boolean to Boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android's memory and threading model is inherited from Java. Android does not alter this model in any way.

The reason why you can manipulate `write_complete` variable in `AsyncTask`'s `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()` is that these methods run on UI thread. Therefore, if you also read the value of `write_complete` in UI thread, there is no multithreading involved.

If, on the other hand, you would change the value of `write_complete` in `doInBackground()` method (which is executed on background thread), then you would have to make the access to this variable thread safe.

In this simple case of a single boolean variable that is being assigned `true` or `false` values, you have three main choices:

1. Declare the variable as volatile in order to make any change immediately visible to all the threads
2. Synchronize the access to the variable explicitly using a lock (this is the one that involves `synchronize` keyword)
3. Use `AtomicBoolean` instead of a simple boolean

The general answer is: **any mutable state accessed by more than one thread must be made thread-safe explicitly**.

Note the "mutable" condition - `final` state is thread-safe by definition.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that doInBackground() actually changes the scope to outside of the UI thread. Also, should synchronize be used in place of volatile when a queue of asynchronous threads cannot be enforced? As in, if you can guarantee that no more than 1 thread at a time will access the variable, then it would be OK to use volatile? As I understand, synchronize will block future accessors of the variable until it is released.

Comment: @DavidMaki,  `volatile` is enough even when multiple threads access the variable concurrently as long as it is a simple variable, its mutation is atomic and each individual thread either reads the variable, or writes it (but not both). I can't really go deeper than this in a scope of SO answer, and strongly recommend you to find a good tutorial on multithreading in java because this is a broad and complex topic. I can recommend this series of tutorials by Jacob Jenkov: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/index.html